# Kendo Grid for Angular 2 virtual scroll

Tags: angular, grid, kendo-grid

Faced with a virtual scrolling issue with Grid for Angular 2. Grid just scroll over first page and then the PageChangeEvent does not fires. I can scroll down but it is just empty space. What can affect PageChangeEvent? How ever when I scroll up on to the most top, PageChangeEvent being fired but fields are {scroll: NaN, take: undefined}. Any ideas?

I guess may be it because of dependencies? 
Here is my pachage.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
 "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
 "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.24.0",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.38.2",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.26.1",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.23.1",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.12.0",
 "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^0.3.0",
 "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.5.1",
 "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^0.14.0",
 "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.28.0",
 "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
 "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
 "lodash": "^4.17.4",
 "lodash.camelcase": "^4.3.0",
 "ngx-toastr": "^5.0.6",
 "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
 "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.4"},

 "devDependencies": {
 "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
 "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
 "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
 "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
 "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
 "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.2",
 "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
 "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
 "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
 "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
 "karma": "~1.4.1",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
 "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
 "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
 "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
 "protractor": "~5.1.0",
 "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
 "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
 "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
 "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
 "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
 "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
 "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
 "tslint": "~4.5.0",
 "typescript": "~2.2.0",
 "webpack": "^2.3.3",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
 "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
 "xml2js": "^0.4.17"}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed [pageSize] kendo-grid parameter.